# Returning count in SQL grouped by two other partitions with an in clause on an id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query that locates all users that have the same email as  (memberid) in the membership table and brings back any other users with matching emails

```
select tenant,first,last,memberid,email,ipaddress,password
from membership
where email IN (
  SELECT email
  FROM membership where memberid = <Parameters.Member ID>
  GROUP BY email)
```

I also need to be able to bring back a count of all users that have the same password or ipaddress as the current row's user. I have tried using a case statement and cannot get the correct results.

Comment: what platform are you running on - mySql, SQL Server, DB2, Oracle or something else?

Comment: you say "the same password or ipaddress as the user member =" But I don't know what the "user member =" means, can you explain

Comment: I need the password and ipaddress to be the same as memberid = <Parameters.Member ID> (which is just a tableau parameter) password or ip address. it sits as memberid in the membership table. this is sql server. Say if it were on memberID = 2415 and their password is helpsql I would want a count of all other users with that password. Same for ip if their ip is 11.22.123.123, I would want a count of other users with that same ip

Comment: I got it, I edited the question to make it clearer (I think) and also wrote you an answer that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hogan got posted the correct answer before I was done  +1
Can also use a join

```
select match.email, match.tenant, match.first, match.last
     , match.memberid, match.ipaddress, match.password  
     , count(match.memberid) OVER (partition by match.ipaddress) as ipCount 
     , count(match.memberid) OVER (partition by match.password) as passwordCount
     , member.memberid as [member.memberid], member.ipaddress as [member.ipaddress], member.password as [member.password]
  from membership as match
  join membership as member
        on member.email = match.email 
       and member.memberid = <Parameters.Member ID>
```

Answer (score 2):

In many platforms (including sql server) you can use a windowing function.  A windowing function would allow you to give a count of the users that have the same password or ipaddress as the current row.  If this is what you want

```
select tenant,first,last,memberid,email,ipaddress,password,
       count(memberid) OVER (partition by ipaddress) as ipaddress_count,
       count(memberid) OVER (partition by password) as password_count
from membership
where email IN (
  SELECT email
  FROM membership where memberid = <Parameters.Member ID>
  GROUP BY email)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    DECLARE @memberid as nvarchar(100)

    SELECT COUNT(member_id) FROM membership
    WHERE email IN (SELECT email from membership WHERE memberid = @memberid)
```

Comment: @Hogan, can you clarify what topic starter is asking for? Need to start somewhere to achieve a goal

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. If you want to help a novice do the task with him

Comment: Read the comment either: "Say if it were on memberID = 2415 and their password is helpsql I would want a count of all other users with that password. Same for ip if their ip is 11.22.123.123, I would want a count of other users with that same ip" – peters 6 mins ago

Comment: Yes but he wants it for all users with emails that match the incoming parameter which is an **id for a user**.  password and email are not parameters.  Please read my answer to see the correct way to do this.  You can also do a sub-query that looks like your answer and join to it, but windowing functions are faster.